# problem with creating reactjs app with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, npx

I created a react app using `npx create-react-app client-app --use-npm --typescript`
I expect to create a project using typescript but after a while it create a project that use `index.js` and `app.js` instead of `index.tsx` and `app.tsx`.
Is there any problem with my command line?

and file `tsconfig.json` is not created
thanks

Comment: Maybe try this, it worked for me: [how to create react app with typescript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWpmPP4z8HE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `npx create-react-app client-app --template typescript`.

See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/#installation.